# ASP.NET MVC 3, pass the file from server to client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, download

Actually, this looks like the download feature, allowing a user to determine the local path where the file should be stored.

The whole thing is: the background program will generate a data file in the server, after that, I want to pass the data file from server to client.
I used `FileStreamResult` and `FileContentResult`, but it doesn't work.

A *.csv file was generated, then the file needs to transfer to the client. in controller , the code is very simple , like `return new FilePathResult(filePath,"text/csv");` and I set the break point , the code execute without any exception , but I didn't see any web diaglog letting the user to select the path to save the csv file.

Comment: Whats exactly your problem? `It dosn't work` is not an appropriate description to get help!

Comment: Please tell us more on what you've tried

Comment: a *.csv file was generated, then the file need transfer to client.  in controller , the code is very simple , like return new FilePathResult(filePath,"text/csv");   and I set the break point , the code execute without any exception ,  but I didn't see any web diaglog let user to select the path to save the csv file.

Comment: How are you calling the controller action?

Comment: Show the exact code of your controller action and of your view. Have you checked with fiddler what is being sent between server and client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using return File()

```
public FileResult GetFile()
{
    byte[] test = { 0 };
    return File(test, "text/csv","TempFile.csv");
}
```

and calling it with an actionlink.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File","GetFile","Home")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I changed the designe--place the csv file under the web root directory, (e.g. \File\Date\testing.csv)  in the Controller method will return a json which point to the csv location (e.g. /File/Date/testing.csv) , the js should get the url and redirect to the /File/Date/testing.csv .

```
    public FastJsonResult Download()
    { 
        //generate the csv file under root path

        //return the url point to the file

        return JsonView(path);
    }
```